# Automatically update local Git repository

Tags: git

I want to clone a GitHub repository that's not mine, and keep this local cloned repository always up to date, that is, whenever a new commit is made upstream, my local repository is also updated automatically.

My use case is CI/CD, I need to clone repositories several times in my jobs, if I had a local GitHub cache it'd be way faster.

Is this possible?

Comment: Sure, set up a cron job to update your local copy.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to use a cron job to update the git repository. If you're running Linux or MacOS, from the terminal run:

```sh
crontab -e
```

This will take you to a CLI text editor. Add the following entry:

```sh
*/5 * * * * cd <full path to your local git repository> && git pull
```

Every 5 minutes (change `5` to something else if you want more frequent updates) this will pull the latest from the remote repository.

There might be a more efficient way to do this but anything simple will require polling since a GitHub repository that's not yours won't be able to push notify upon change. Cron is fairly lightweight anyway.

Comment: `5` is "every hour at :05". If you want "every 5 minutes", use `*/5` in the first column

Comment: Ah yes good point, thanks. Updated!